# How do I trim whitespace from a string(right left and between spaces)?

Tags: python

I want to remove any extra whitespace in a sentece how can i do this with python?
for ex :

```
("  hello   world") >>>  ("hello world")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = " hello     world "
str_clean = ' '.join(str.split())
print(str_clean)

hello world
```

Edited, I think I overlooked your initial text.

Comment: i cant trim between the whitespace at the sentence

Comment: Yes, I noticed you might have edited the text or I didn't notice that, updated the answer :)